# GWT: Stack overflow when returning ArrayList<String> on IE

Tags: java, gwt

I have a service

```
ArrayList<String> getTexts( int clientId );
```

When I call it I get the message Stack Overflow in IE.

Comment: Can you paste the pseudocode so we can understand it in detail? And does it only comes in IE, or firefox or chrome also?

Comment: Maybe it is a hidden marketing ploy for this website :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ouchi. I had an recursion in a getter that is called in the onSuccess method when calling the service.

```
public HTML getIntroductionHTML() {
    return getIntroductionHTML();
}
```